# С чего начать изучение MySQL?

Tags: mysql

С чего начать изучать программирование на MySQL (хотя бы авторов книг и название книг)?

Answer (score 1):

Авторы книги: Максим Кузнецов, Игорь Симдянов. Название: Самоучитель MySQL 5.

Тут посмотреть: [Учебник по MySQL](http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/db/mysql/mysql2/mysql.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

- Джо Селко - SQL
- Мишель Е. Дэвис и
     Джон А. Филлипс - Изучаем PHP и MySQL

Они хорошие особенно первая книжка - Всё ясно и понятно изложено хорошая сказка на ночь :)
И конечно куда без банальностей? Лучше не электронную ибо качество и читабельность ниже (И самое неприятно глаза могут болеть %) )

Удачи! :DDD

Comment: Лучше мануал и много много практики, никакая книга этого не заменит, прочитай хоть 10 книг...<br>
Я в свое время просто открыл гугл, консоль, и понеслась %)

Comment: Меня книжки попросили найти вот я и нашел ^^ А книжки и вправду хорошие...Тем более многим требуются примеры.
<br /><br />
ps. Я в свое время просто открыл гугл, консоль, и понеслась %) +1 ^^
<br />я так (примерно) php учил =)

Answer (score 1):

да и лучше всего начинать с мануала, тем более мускул очень хорошо документирован

Answer (score 1):

Если просто хочется научится программировать с использованием MySQL боюсь, что ничего не выйдет. Как не банально будет звучать, нужно начинать с реальной или на худой конец выдуманной задачи.

Например как хранить в MySQL каталог товаров: категории, сами товары, их наличие. Нарисовать на бумаге таблицы с их связями, а потом смотреть (в книге или в поисковике) необходимые функции.